# Why crontab don't working?

Tags: cron

In linux:with crontab: I test with as : 
  `* * * * * /bin/echo "xin chao">> /home/iloveyou/text.txt` . It work fine.

But when i test run an url:

```
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/curl -k https://192.169.30.126/joomlandk2/index.php/exportmanager
```

It's don't working. when i run as: `/usr/bin/curl -k https://192.169.30.126/joomlandk2/index.php/exportmanager` from Terminal window. It run ok.
Why? I want set run  `https://192.169.30.126/joomlandk2/index.php/exportmanager` with crontab. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: See authentication because the process crond runs under its own environment and under another login as you under a terminal

Comment: How do you fixed the problem?

Comment: 1) In crontab, put a call to a shell script. 2) in the shell, echo or/and set environment before calling curl to have similar conditions of your own environment

Comment: I'm sorry , Can you give me an example?

Comment: Ok, I'll develop in an answer

Comment: In my case, I accidentally had the word "root" before the command in the crontab line. It was also helpful to add logging by appending this to the crontab line: ` >> /code/cron.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At OP request this answer details how to step-by-step, duplicate user environment in crond context.

In crontab, put a call to a shell script.

```
*/3 * * * * /home/userX/dir/exportmanager.sh
```

In the shell, echo or/and set environment before calling curl to have similar conditions of your own environment.

Https use SSL keys, how curl looks for this keys, in which certificate repository?

See `--capath` option.

```
#!/bin/bash
set VAR=value
/usr/bin/curl -k https://192.169.30.126/joomlandk2/index.php/exportmanager\
   >/home/userX/dir/exportmanager.log
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be some special characters issue. Put the command into a wrapper script, add run permission rights and switch crontab to point to it.